# AnyLogic - How to assign multiple resources from one resource pool to single agent?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am simulating a ticketing system - For ex. I have received a request about major electrical failure for a machine in the manufacturing plant. I wish to assign all available electricians to resolve the issue. In my model - incoming request is agent and electrician as resources.

So, I have wish to assign all available resources in a particular resourcePool to a single agent at a time within a service block? How to do it?

Comment: what if there are no resources available?

Comment: @Felipe - Please advise that too - how to keep it waiting in the service block queue when available no of resources is 0

Answer (score 0):

In your seize block you can choose " units of the same pool" and then in the number of units section write a formula, like the one in the screenshot below, so that you can seize all the units that are available.

[image]